# data being written to file is not appearing

Tags: java, android, outputstream, fileoutputstream

in one of the activities when a button is pressed i want to create a file on the extran storage. so i wrote
the below code to do so.

but in the end the file is created but empty..why?

**code**:

```
public void tx(byte[] data) {
    Log.w(TAG, CSubTag.bullet("tx"));

    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "test.txt");
    try {
        file.createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file);
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(os);
        try {
            bos.write("data_stream".getBytes());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: ' file.createNewFile();'. Remove that. That complete try-catch block. It serves nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Please close the OutputStream  and BufferedOutputStream inside finally block. Otherwise, the data will not be written.